# MIPS Printing Error

Tags: hex, output, mips

So I'm sure I went wrong somewhere in my code but I'm trying to convert integers the user entered into the program into Hex. My first problem is that I can't seem to get the program to print the integer entered. Rather it seems to print the address of the integer. 
Here is the code:

```
.data # Data declaration
  # A+B -(C-D x E)

    string1: .asciiz "Please enter an integer from range 0 to 32768: "
    string2: .asciiz "Next integer: "
    string3: .asciiz "Invalid input. Start over: "
    string4: .asciiz "The hexadecimal value of the decimal integer "
    string5: .asciiz "is: "
    newline: .asciiz "\n"
    .align 2
    userinput: .space 100
    var6: .asciiz "The result of A+B -(C-D x E) is: "
.text

main:
    la $a0, string1 #load string one and print
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $s0, 1
    la $a1, userinput 
    li $t1, 5 #set temporary variable to 5
    li $t0, 0 #start of counter

input:  
    beq $t0, $t1, exit
    li $v0, 5 # read integer
    syscall
    blt $v0, $zero, invalid # if input is less than zero
    bgt $v0, 32768, invalid # if input is greater than 32768
    beq $t0, 0, case1
    beq $t0, 1, case2
    beq $t0, 2, case3
    beq $t0, 3, case4
    beq $t0, 4, case5

case1: 
    sw $v0, 0($a1)
    addi $t0, 1
    la $a0, string2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j input
case2: 
    sw $v0, 4($a1)
    addi $t0, 1
    la $a0, string2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j input 
case3: 
    sw $v0, 8($a1)
    addi $t0, 1
    la $a0, string2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j input
case4: 
    sw $v0, 12($a1)
    addi $t0, 1
    la $a0, string2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j input
case5: 
    sw $v0, 16($a1)
    addi $t0, 1
    la $a0, string2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j input
invalid: 
    la $a0, string3 #load string one and print
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    j input

exit:
    la $t3, userinput # stores base address of user input array into $t3
    li $t1, 1
    li $t0, 0

    la $a0, string4 # load string4
    li $v0, 4 # print
    syscall

    move $a0, $t3 # move first number into a0
    li $v0, 1 # print
    syscall

    la $a0, string5
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    jal convert

    li $t1, 1
    jal hexconvert

    addi $s0, $s0, 1
    slti $t7, $s0, 6
    bne $t2, $zero, exit

    j close

convert:
    andi $t4, $t3, 15
    sll $s4, $s4, 8
    slti $t5, $t4, 10
    bne $t5, $zero, else
    addi $t4, $t4, 65
    jal next
else:   
    addi $t4, $t4, 48

next:   
    add $s4, $s4, $t3
    srl $t3, $t3, 4
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    slti $t5, $t1, 5
    bne $t5, $zero, convert
    jr $ra
hexconvert:
    andi $t4, $s4, 255
    move $a0, $t4
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    srl $s4, $s4, 8
    addi $s3, $s3, 1
    slti $t1, $s3, 5
    bne $t2, $zero, hexconvert
    la $a0, newline
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    jr $ra

close:  
    li $v0, 10 # exit instruction
    syscall
```

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I'm still very new to MIPS.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't seem to get the program to print the integer entered. Rather it seems to print the address of the integer.

Printing the address appears to be exactly what you're doing here:

```
la $t3, userinput # stores base address of user input array into $t3

...

move $a0, $t3 # move first number into a0
li $v0, 1 # print
syscall
```

The `move $a0, $t3` simply copies the value of `$t3` (i.e. the address of `userinput`) into `$a0`. If what you really wanted was to read from the memory pointed to by `$t3` you should've written `lw $a0,($t3)`